# c++ how do I create closures with Variadic?

Tags: c++, closures, std-function, variadic, pybind11

I'm trying to rewrite this python code to its equivalent pybind c++.
But I can't get my c++ code to accept an unknown amount of arguments

python:

```
def primitive(f_raw):
    def f_wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return f_raw(*args, **kwargs)
    return f_wrapped
```

c++:

```
template <class... T>
std::function<T(T...)> primative(std::function<T(T...)> callable)
{
  return [=](T... params){
    return callable(params...);
  };
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to achieve? At least for the c++ case the returned callable will be identical to what you pass in, except that it will pass everything by value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 2 template params here

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
std::function<T(Ts...)> primative(std::function<T(Ts...)> callable)
{
  return [=](Ts... params){
    return callable(params...);
  };
}
```

`Ts...` is a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), it can contain any types.

Comment: what would be the correct way of using the function `const auto bound = primative(xtadd<sometype>);bound(1,2);`

Comment: [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) link provides all ways of usage.